# Showing that if $f(x) \leq |x|^2, \forall x \in \mathrm{R}^n$, then $f$ is differentiable at $0_n$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, derivatives

Currently I'm not sure how to argue about the existence of f's differentiable. Namely, let $f: \mathrm{R}^n \to \mathrm{R}^m$ such that $|f(x)|\leq |x|^2, \forall x \in \mathrm{R}^n$. We will show that $f$ is differentiable at $0_n$. In this problem the (equivalent) definition of differentiability is that $f$ is differentiable at an interior point $a$, if there exists a linear mapping $T_a$ such that $f(a + h) - f(a) - T_a(h)$ is $\mathcal{o}(h)$, where $\forall \phi \in \mathcal{o}(h): \forall \epsilon > 0:\exists \delta_\epsilon > 0: |h| < \delta_\epsilon \implies |\phi(h)| < \epsilon$. Moreover a given property of Landau spaces is that if $f$ and $g$ are functions and $f$ is $\mathcal{o}(h)$ and $\exists \delta_f > 0: |h| < \delta_f \implies |g(h)| \leq |f(h)|$, then also $g$ is $\mathcal{o}(h)$. Then as the vector space and product properties of Landau spaces, $f, g \in \mathcal{o}(h) \implies f + g \in \mathcal{o}(h)$ and $f \in \mathcal{o}(1), g \in \mathcal{O}(h) \implies fg \in \mathcal{o}(h)$ show that $|x|^2$ is in $\mathcal{o}(h)$, it follows that $f$ is in $\mathcal{o}(h)$ as well.

And that is as far as I get in my reasoning. If I assume/show that $x|^2$ has a differentiable at $0_n$, then I can use the inequality $||0_n + h|^2 - |0_n|^2 - T_{0_n}(h)| \geq |f(0_n + h) - f(0_n) - T_{0_n}(h)|$ to show that a differentiable exists for $f$, but is there some other way?

Comment: $|f(h+0_n)-f(0_n)|=|f(h)|\leq h^2\in o(h)$

Comment: @kingW3 I presume that here we can readily apply the uniqueness of the derivative to argue that the zero mapping is *the* derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differential is zero. Namely,
$$
0 \le \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|f(h) - \overbrace{f(0)}^{=0} - \overbrace{0}^{\text{our differential}} \cdot h\|}{\|h\|} \le \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\|h\|^2}{\|h\|} = 0.
$$

Comment: It should be $f(h) - f(0) - 0 \cdot h$ in the numerator.

Comment: Although strictly speaking they are the same, I agree that this would make it more readable.